# Tensorflow, problem loading checkpoint for object detection via fine-tuning[Not available in checkpoint]

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have been trying to load a checkpoint of "faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous" pre-trained on openimages. I am receiving an error that says some of the values are missing in the checkpoint. Given, I have worked with other models and did not receive this error.

I ran inspect_checkpoint.py on the model and noticed that there are actually missing parts. Here is part of the error log.

> W0204 17:09:30.737426  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
>   W0204 17:09:30.738423  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
>   W0204 17:09:30.738423  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/biases/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
>   W0204 17:09:30.739422  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/weights/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
>   W0204 17:09:30.740419  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
>   W0204 17:09:30.741417  3724 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint

Basically all values with "Momentum" in the end are missing.
Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue, the momentum values were not saved to the model, but since you're fine-tuning (rather than continuing training from the same spot), you don't want to load and use these values, let them be initialized.